# Mongoose not storing a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When i go and check my database ,i cant see the studentNamer field there. its like i am never saving it.cant seen to understand what is happening. Why would it be skipping one field which is of type string , while saving other files of type string?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose/');

var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var studentInfoSchema = new Schema({
    tty: String,
    StudentNamer :  String,
    id  : Number,
    tt: String,
    numberOfterms  : Number
}, {collection: 'studentInfoDatabaseModel'});



var studentInfoDatabaseModel=mongoose.model( 'studentInfoDatabaseModel', studentInfoSchema);


    mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/sss' );
var db=mongoose.connection;

db
    .on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection error.'))
    .once('open', console.log.bind(console, 'DB Connection established.'));
var newItem=new studentInfoDatabaseModel({
    tty:"kkk",
    studentNamer : "sumiit",
    id: 55,
    tt: "dfdsffsdaaa",
    numberOfterms: 4
});
mongoose.saveToDb=function(){
    newItem.save(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log("there was an err savin");
            }
        });
}

mongoose.findData=function(){
    var posts = db.model('studentInfoDatabaseModel');

    posts.find({id : 55}, function(err, calls) {
        console.log(err, calls, calls.length);  //prints out: null [] 0
        var u1= calls[0].id;
       var u= calls[0].studentName;
    });
}

exports.mongoose=mongoose;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared it in the schema as `StudentNamer` (note the "**S**") but you are trying to save it as `studentNamer : "sumiit"` (note the "**s**"), so just change it to:

```
var studentInfoSchema = new Schema({
    tty: String,
    studentNamer :  String,
    id  : Number,
    tt: String,
    numberOfterms  : Number
}, {collection: 'studentInfoDatabaseModel'});
```